# Dimension of a Border in a Canvas

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, shapes

I do :
    myCanvas.Children.Add(laCase);

laCase is a Border with stuff inside. Just after i would like to have the exact center of laCase.

But ***ActualWidth*** and ***ActualHeight*** equal ***0***

While ***Width*** and ***Height*** are ***NaN***.

I tried to mess with myCanvas.Children without any success.

Is there a flush or something to do to actualize myCanvas and picking the dimensions i'm looking for ?

Comment: A Canvas never sets the size of its child elements. Use some other container, e.g. a Grid.

Comment: la case is a border. i tried with the grid without any change.

Comment: I mean use a Grid instead of a Canvas. If you put the Border into a Canvas without setting its size, its ActualWidth and ActualHeight will be zero because the Canvas does not resize its child elements.

Answer (score -1):

Found the answer.

I found : Canvas.Arrange(Rect);

Comment: `UIElement.Arrange` is a method that is called by WPF when a control needs to be updated to resize itself or its children. If you are ever calling it manually, you are either doing some advanced stuff and know what you are doing, or (more likely) you don't know what you are doing and are using it wrong. Even when you do need to call it manually, you will almost always call it indirectly by using `UIElement.InvalidateMeasure` or `UIElement.InvalidateVisual` instead.

Comment: i do :  
    myCanvas.Children.Add(laCase);
    laCase.InvalidateMeasure();
    double width = laCase.ActualWidth;